# Can't Import Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, anaconda

Maybe I wasn't clear before so I am reformatting the whole question.  There is most likely some error with my path variables that I don't know how to fix...

I have a script entitled test.py:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.csv_read("nbaData.csv")
```

When running this script I get this error:

```
C:\Users\joeblow\Desktop\repos\BitBucket\basketball>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: No module named numpy not built. If you want to import
 pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ex
t --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

When typing `conda install pandas`

```
C:\Users\joeblow\Desktop\repos\BitBucket\basketball>conda install pandas
Fetching package metadata: C:\Users\joeblow\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\p
ackages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext obje
ct is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately an
d may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://u
rllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
....
Solving package specifications: .
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\joeblow\Anaconda:
#
pandas                    0.16.2               np19py27_0
```

THIS QUESTION CAN BE DELETED BY A MODERATOR.  My solution involved uninstalling and reinstalling python on my computer

Comment: `pip uninstall pandas` and `conda install pandas` should suffice to make pandas work if you configured `anaconda` correctly as your default python distribution.

Comment: I assume that I didn't properly configure anaconda as my default python distribution

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that Conda does not have all of your packages, I'd suggest using Anaconda and follow those instructions it has all the packages, including Pandas no need to install anything else on Windows..

```
C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda>python
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

Comment: Have you started Anaconda? Show all your starting code?

Comment: You should start python by clicking on the anaconda command prompt item in the windows start menu then see something like this:
C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda>python

Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pandas
*** See above edit***** in answer

Comment: I am trying to import pandas from a script.  I go to command prompt and type `python add_data.py --update` which is a script I have written.  Before I was using the csv module to append columns to a csv and re write it, but to be more efficient I want to load it into a pandas data frame.  I have used pandas on a prior computer but am having issues on this computer...

Comment: see above, your path is getting messed up since you are not starting within the Anaconda directory

Comment: Ok I can type in import pandas and I get no error, however I can't run my script, as it still gives me the same error message that I initially posted